# How should I approach the html placeholder attribute scenario automation with webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Hi I need to automate a sceanrio where a text input field is there, where a text - 
"type here" is displayed.

```
<input class="textbox" type="text" value="" placeholder="type here" name="q">
```

I need to verify
1) Text is displayed - "type here"
2) When focus is moved to this text field, the text input field does not display - 
"type here"

Comment: Did you already try using driver.webelement.getText()?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Or: How should I test an input field with a 'placeholder' element?

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether the browser supports the `placeholder` attribute for `<input>` elements via a simple JavaScript. This is an indirect test, but as far as I know, you can't test for the placeholder text via Selenium. But it should be absolutely sufficient:

```js
function supportsInputPlaceholder() {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    return 'placeholder' in input;
}
```

(taken from http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/detect.html#input-placeholder)

Therefore:

```java
// only if your driver supports JS
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String placeholderTest = "return 'placeholder' in document.createElement('input')";
assertTrue(js.executeScript(placeholderTest));
```