# Determine if placeholder text is displayed in protractor test

Tags: selenium, input, selenium-webdriver, protractor, placeholder

How can you check to determine if placeholder text is actually being displayed for an input field in a protractor test?

[image]

Using the following I am able to check the placeholder text that is displayed but it returns whether it is actually displayed or not:

```
this.groupName.getAttribute( 'placeholder' )
```

Comment: Please post the text of the HTML instead of a picture. At some point in the future images will be invalid and this question will be less useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scoping problem and something your browser knows how to handle. *You should not test your browser's ability to interpret placeholder and show it*. Checking that there is a desired `placeholder` attribute value set is good enough.

You may, though, [test if your browser supports `placeholder` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13585170/771848).

Comment: Browsers that don't support it should just ignore it.